# Word Length Frequency using parallel array lists

Tags: java

So for my homework, I am tasked to grab a chapter and find the length of the words, and how many times they appear(the most frequency and the least) for example length 3 frequency 324. I'm not looking for the answer, because I will not learn that way. I am just looking for a bit of guidance.

```
 import java.io.File;
 import java.io.FileNotFoundException; 
 import java.util.Scanner;
 import java.util.ArrayList;
public class WordLengthFrequency{
public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException{
    Scanner input = new Scanner(new File("Chapter1.txt"));
    ArrayList<String> text = new ArrayList<String>();
    ArrayList<String> length = new ArrayList<String>();
    ArrayList<String> frequency = new ArrayList<String>();
    while(input.hasNext()){
        String token = input.next();
        String word = token.replace("!","");
        String word2 = token.replace("?","");
        String word3 = token.replace(".","");
        String word4 = token.replace(",","");
        String word5 = token.replace(":","");
        String word6 = token.replace(";","");
        text.add(token);
    }

    System.out.println("Top 3 most frequently occurring word length: ");
    System.out.println("Least frequently occuring word length:");
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

You can use a Hashmap of <token, frequency> instead of a list.

Before you put any token into the map, check if it's there in the map.

If it exists , get the frequency for that key, and increment,update its value for the key.

If it doesn't exists, just add that token (key) and 1 ( frequency) as it's value in theap.

This way you can avoid duplicates, not iterating through the list unnecessarily..

Some useful methods in hashmap are put, putifabsent, get, containsKey.